# How to make style in ListView SelectedItem.?

Tags: wpf, listview, styles

I am working on a WPF application and I want to make style on `ListViewItem`. I have made a style for this but this does not give me the exact result what I want. Apart from this I want `CornerRadius` in this style so how I can add this?

```
            <ListView x:Name="MenuBarList" 
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Height="{Binding MainMenuHeight}"  
                    Width="{Binding MainMenuWidth}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu.Options}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMainMenuOption, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    IsTabStop="False">

                <ListView.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/> 
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#9449b0"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#9449b0"/>
                    </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Style>


                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Source="{Binding IconPath}" 
                                   Focusable="False"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                       Focusable="False" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                       FontSize="26"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quick solution is to override item template. You may reffer to WPF or Silverlight themes about contols styling. See the [BureauBlue.xaml](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WPF.Themes/BureauBlue/Theme.xaml) for ListViewItem complete template.

```
<ListView x:Name="uiList">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    CornerRadius="5" x:Name="border">
                <ContentControl 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                    Margin="2,2,2,2" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListViewItem Content="10" />
    <ListViewItem Content="11" />
</ListView>
```

Comment: My desired Result is I want ot SeletedItem will highlight with pink color and accordingly the cornerRadius will required.

Comment: I had put my code into the XAML so you can look at and just I want round corner of selectedItem.

Comment: I had to add GridViewRowPresenter into ContentControl so that ListViewItem will show the actual item that was bound to it otherwise it will show the name of class that was bound to ListView's ItemsSource. btw, BureauBlue.xaml link is dead, Could you update it?

Comment: @witoong623 I have updated the link to the closes equivalent. Regarding your obstacles, ContentControl do not define what to show. Your ItemTemplate and bindings define how to show Items which you have bound to the list. So, no GridViewRowPresenter required if you bind text directly or use ItemTemplate to be more specific on which item property you would like to show.