# WPF, How to style the items in ListView such as the background color of an item when it's selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, desktop-application

When I select an item I want the background color of the item to be this color #d3ddff instead of the default color https://imgur.com/n5KDzx6

When I hover over an item I want the background color of  the item to be just white

After clicking the item and I click the TextBox that has "body 2" to type something, the background color of the selected item should still be #d3ddff instead of the white color like this https://imgur.com/mFXxFDS Also in the image you can see that the | of TextBox is black, how can I set it to white so that the user knows that he/she has selected the TextBox or is typing?

Also, when I click on an item and press the ALT key the item has now a dotted outline around it, how can I get rid of it? like this https://imgur.com/WVuhQpt

This is the full source code of my XAML

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Notes.WPF.Views.NotesListingView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:dropdownmenucontrol="clr-namespace:DropdownMenuControl;assembly=DropdownMenuControl"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Notes.WPF.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:whitedropdownmenucontrol="clr-namespace:WhiteDropdownMenuControl;assembly=WhiteDropdownMenuControl"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Height="40"
            Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"
            Content="Add a new note" />

        <Border
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,20,0,0"
            CornerRadius="5"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Border}" />
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
                <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="White"
                    CornerRadius="5" />

                <ListView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Background="#2b2d30"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding NotesListingItemViewModel}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotesListingItemViewModel}">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Padding="10">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" />

                                    <whitedropdownmenucontrol:WhiteDropdownMenu Grid.Column="1">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <Button
                                                Width="200"
                                                Height="40"
                                                Padding="10"
                                                Content="MARKED AS COMPLETE" />
                                            <Button
                                                Width="200"
                                                Height="40"
                                                Padding="10"
                                                Content="MARKED AS IMPORTANT" />
                                            <Button
                                                Width="200"
                                                Height="40"
                                                Padding="10"
                                                Content="DELETE" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </whitedropdownmenucontrol:WhiteDropdownMenu>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>

        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I can't find it in google that really helps me and solves the issues I have. ChatGPT and Google Bard can't give answers that actually helps

Comment: There seems to be more than one question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to ChatGPT and Google Bard my issues, doesnt work. I've tried these links but none really helped me [link 1](https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/12158/how-to-apply-the-selected-item-background-color-when-the-itemtemplate-view-has-a-background) [link 2](https://dotnetpattern.com/how-apply-listview-itemcontainerstyle) [link 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-use-triggers-to-style-selected-items-in-a-listview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150928/how-to-make-style-in-listview-selecteditem)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the problem correctly, below I made the style that you need to put in your ItemContainerStyle, I used triggers to change the background.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                    Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="#d3ddff" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

"dotted outline around" is the style when it is focused with the keyboard and is called FocusVisualStyle, I set it to null at ListViewItem.
But you have several elements in the ItemTemplate, and you should set FocusVisualStyle = "{x:null} for all of them.

To not affect ListViewItem , all items in ItemTemplate set Background = "Transparent".